# Checking if an array contaisObject:@(float) in Objective-C can unexpectedly return NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsnumber

I have some method that receives a `float` as an argument, and checks to see if this float is in an array. To do this, I first convert the float to a `NSNumber`. This is a testable simplification of my code:

```
float aFloat = 0.3;
NSNumber *aNSNumber = @(aFloat);

NSArray *anArray = @[@(0.0), @(0.3), @(1.0)];
NSLog(@"%d", [anArray containsObject:aNSNumber]);
```

This code will log `0` (i.e. `NO`), so it's saying that `0.3`is not in `anArray`. If `aFloat` is a "round" number such as `0.0`, `0.5`, or `1.0`, the test works and logs `1` (i.e. `YES`). Any number other than that, like the `0.3` above, fails.

In the other hand, if we change `aFloat` to be a `double`, it works. Or, if we change `anArray` to this:

```
NSArray *array = @[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
```

It also works. What I presumed is that the NSNumber `@()` notation creates a `numberWithDouble:`.

But, my question is, shouldn't it work even when `aFloat` is a `float`? Since I'm "converting" it anyways by saving it in `aNSNumber`... And shouldn't it automatically recognize that the `float` `0.3` and the `double` `0.3` are actually the same numbers? Also, why the "round" numbers works anyway?

Comment: float and double are not the same type, so why should NSNumber go to the trouble of hashing them as the same type?

Comment: @CodaFi because after I created them, they should all be the same NSNumber. In my opinion, it shouldn't matter how you created the NSNumber — they represent the same "real world" number (0.3 in this case), so the NSNumber created with the `float` 0.3 should be the same as the NSNumber created with the `double` 0.3. They should be only differentiable after you got their values from NSNumber using `floatValue` or `doubleValue`.

Comment: Why on earth are you using float and not double? Never use float _unless you can give a good reason to do so_. In this case, it bit you in the arse. And to the compiler, your opinion doesn't count. Especially when you're wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@(0.3)` uses `-numberWithDouble:` because `0.3` has type `double`. If you wrote `@(0.3f)` then it would use `-numberWithFloat:`.

Neither `float` nor `double` can store 0.3 exactly. (It's similar to the problem of writing 1/3 in decimal form - you can't do it exactly using a finite number of digits.) Instead, you get the `float` closest to 0.3 and the `double` closest to 0.3. These two numbers are not equal to each other, so `-containsObject:` can't find a match.

Both `float` and `double` can store 0.0 and 1.0 exactly, so both conversions give you the same result and `-containsObject:` succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

The `@(0.3)` in the `anArray` is a `double` wrapped in an `NSNumber`. And of course your `aFloat` is a `float` wrapped in an `NSNumber`.

Try one of the two possible changes:

1) Change `float aFloat` to `double aFloat`

or

2) Change `@(0.3)` in `anArray` to `@(0.3f)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have these solutions as I stated in my question. What I'm looking to is actually some sort of "why" this works like this... See my last paragraph for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize the difference between 0.3 and 0.3f with this snippet:

```
NSLog(@"%.20f %.20f", 0.3, 0.3f);
```

My debugger shows: 0.29999999999999998890 0.30000001192092895508

Funny enough, the '0.3' appears more accurate than the '0.3f'. Anyway, I *speculate* that the compiler may take the straight 0.3 as a double first before converting it to a float whereas the 0.3f specification is a float immediately.

Another thing to observe is had you done this:

```
NSArray *anArray = @[@(0.0), aNSNumber, @(1.0)];
```

The containsObject call would have succeeded. Perhaps the compiler's route to convert the float into whatever it uses internally between the aFloat declaration and the literal has some differences. Just speculating here...

In general, I don't like testing for equality with floats or doubles for that matter. Accuracy problems can through you for a loop just too easily.

Comment: "Funny enough, the '0.3' appears more accurate than the '0.3f'". Nothing strange about that at all. `0.3` is a `double` (double precision floating type) while `0.3f` is  a `float` (single precision floating type). I'd say it's very much as expected.

Comment: Ah didn't know that. I guess it makes sense the double is the compiler's default.

Comment: It's not specifically the compiler's default. It's defined by the C language spec.

Comment: And the %f format expects a double argument (and float is converted to double as a printf argument, but at that point it's too late, the precision is already lost).